# Raphael Text Glow

Tags: raphael

Does anyone have an idea of how to get a glow to show up on text? I thought it would be pretty easy to do so but nothing is rendering on the fiddle.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZPtq/3/)

Thanks

Comment: nothing shows because your fiddle is broken. try testing with [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/7ZPtq/35/), and open the JS console once in a while.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me as though Raphael simply does not support text glow.  Check out the first lines of the glow function:

```
if (this.type == "text") {
    return null;
}
```

It might be worth your while to investigate the use of `print` with a [Cufonized](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) font -- it'll return a path representing the text you give it instead of a tspan, and `glow` *can* be applied to paths.

Or you could settle for creating a simple drop shadow.

I've staged both of these alternatives by way of demonstration [here](http://voidblossom.com/tests/textGlow.php).

Answer (score 1):

You could create a rectangle behind the text and make that glow. I think that should look just fine. Use getBBox() to find out the size of the rectangle you need.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7ZPtq/51/

Or maybe use some other primitive, e.g. line.

Comment: this is the approach i took, i also set the opacity of the rectangle to 0, so you won't see it.